# How to use Azure Powershell to change the stack of an Azure WebApp?

Tags: azure, powershell, web-applications, azure-web-app-service

Does anyone know how to change the stack of an Azure WebApp? For instance when one creates a webapp with New-AzWebApp, the default stack is .NET 4.0. How does one switch that to DOTNETCORE without having to revert to using the portal?
Also how does one specify the stack at creation without resorting to Resource Templates?

Comment: Hi, could it solve your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know, if you use `New-AzWebApp`, you could not specify the stack at creation, but you could use the command below to switch that to `dotnetcore` after creation.

```
New-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName <Resource-Group-Name> -Name <web-app-name> -Location centralus -AppServicePlan <app-service-plan-name>
$PropertiesObject = @{
        "CURRENT_STACK" =  "dotnetcore"
    }
New-AzResource -PropertyObject $PropertiesObject -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName> -ResourceType Microsoft.Web/sites/config -ResourceName "<web-app-name>/metadata" -ApiVersion 2018-02-01 -Force
```

[image]

**Check in the portal:**

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to set a version here as well? as now we have NET Core 3.1, NET .5, etc.